# Is Tom Glavine the only hockey player who was drafted by the NHL, but went on to play another professional sport?

Tags: trivia, mlb, nhl, draft

At his MLB Hall of Fame induction, Tom Glavine noted that he was also drafted to play hockey by the NHL's Los Angeles Kings (1984 draft, 4th round), ahead of Hockey Hall of Famers Brett Hull (6th Round, Calgary Flames) and Luc Robataille (9th Round, Kings).  Two other hall of famers also came from that class, Mario Lemieux and Patrick Roy, making that draft class a great trick hockey-trivia question ("how many hall of famers were drafted in the 1984 NHL Draft?").

Are there other NHL draftees who went on to play another professional sport, or were drafted in another sport and gave that up to play in the NHL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are answers to this question.

[Eric Lindros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Lindros) was a Toronto Blue Jays prospect.

[Jarome Iginla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarome_Iginla) - Played baseball for the Canadian national junior team.  Not sure if he was ever drafted by MLB, though.

[Carl Voss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Voss) - Hockey Hall of Fame inductee won Calder Memorial Trophy and Stanley Cup while in the NHL, also played football for the Queen's Golden Gaels, winning the Grey Cup. He, along with [Lionel Conacher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Conacher) is one of only two people to have their names on both the Stanley Cup and Grey Cup.  Connacher also played professional lacrosse.

[Jeremy Yablonski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Yablonski) - Professional hockey player in Europe and North America, who played one NHL game for the St. Louis Blues, fought professionally in MMA XFS (Extreme Fight Series). He was also a one time, novice Golden Gloves boxing champion.

Answer (score 3):

[Kirk McCaskill](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirk_McCaskill), who pitched for the MLB's California Angels and Chicago White Sox, was drafted by the NHL's Winnipeg Jets in 1981 and played one year of minor-league professional hockey for the Jets' AHL farm team before focusing on baseball fulltime.